# GCS - The project exceeded the rate limit for creating and deleting buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using node.js application running on Google Compute engine to create GCS bucket for each user. The bucket creation is a one time activity for each user. But when I try to run the program to create unique buckets for 20 users in parallel, I am getting the below error.
"Error code":429 and "Error message":"The project exceeded the rate limit for creating and deleting buckets."

Is there anyway I can increase this limit?

Answer (score 2):

No.

There is a per-project rate limit to bucket creation and deletion of approximately 1 operation every 2 seconds, so plan on fewer buckets and more objects in most cases. If you're designing a system that adds many users per second, then design for many users in one bucket (with appropriate ACLs) so that the bucket creation rate limit doesn't become a bottleneck.

See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quotas-limits.